# convergent sequence is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $x_n \to x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, show that the set $\{x\} \cup \{x_n : n\geq 1\}$  is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$.Is the same true if is replaced by some arbitrary metric space $M?$ Is every countable set nowhere dense ? Explain

The metric used for the first part of the question is the regular euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

For the last part of the question $\mathbb{Q}$ would serve as a counter example.
Need some hints will try to finish the proof.

Comment: Do you need any metric in $\mathbb{R}$?  Or do you just need the topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well your set contains its only limit point, so equals its closure (assuming we're working with the standard topology). Can you find any open sets contained in your set?

Comment: @BrianTung, sorry did'nt get your question, the first part is using the regular euclidean metric i guess and the second part is pertaining to any metric space

Comment: For a counterexample to the second question, try an $M$ which is very small...

Comment: @K.Power thanks for the hint, I follow your idea but I have problem expressing it

Comment: "*Is every countable set nowhere dense?*" No. In fact, some countable sets are **everywhere dense**.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes that part is clear , $\mathbb{Q}$ would serve as a good counterexample, it was a textbook question was having trouble with the first two parts .

Comment: A quick hint: what is the cardinality of a (nonempty) open set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For metric spaces in general, consider what happens if the metric space consists of only one point. (This comment comes 15 minutes later because I was playing around with automatically generated math papers I found after clicking on the web page for @Nate Eldredge )

Comment: The set $\{x\}\cup \{x_n:n\geq 1\}$ could be the whole space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sketch on how to present the idea that you're struggling to express. Let $A:=\{x\}\cup\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. By the reason given in my comment $\bar A= A$. Consider some non-empty set $U\subset A$. Assume that $U$ is open. There must then exist some $b>a$ such that $(a,b)\subset U$. However, we know that any interval in $\mathbb R$ has uncountably many elements, contradicting the countability of $A$. I leave you to fill in the details.

Comment: thanks for the excellent proof

Comment: @spaceman_spiff it is by no means an excellent proof, but I'm glad it helped. In fact, I already see an omission I need to fix.